# Offsetting the start time of SQL Server Agent job schedules between instances

Tags: sql-server, job-scheduling, sql-server-agent, sql-agent-job

I have an agent job set to run log backups every two hours from 2:00 AM to 11:59 PM (leaving a window for running a full or differential backup). A similar job is set up in every one of my 50 or so instances. I may be adding several hundred instances over time (we host SQL Servers for some of our customers). They all backup to the same SAN disk volume. This is causing latency issues and otherwise impacting performance.

I'd like to offset the job run times on each instance by 5 minutes, so that instance one would run the job at 2:00, 4:00, etc., instance two would run it at 2:05, 4:05, etc., instance three would run it at 2:10, 4:10, etc. and so on. If I offset the start time for the job on each instance (2:00 for instance one, 2:05 for instance two, 2:10 for instance three, etc.), can I reasonably expect that I will get my desired result of not having all the instances run the job at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the same conversation we just had on twitter: when you tell SQL Server Agent to run every n minutes or every n hours, the next run is based on the *start* time, not the *finish* time. So if you set a job on instance 1 to run at 2:00 and run every 2 hours, the 2nd run will run at 4:00, whether the first run took 1 minute, 12 minutes, 45 minutes, etc.

There are some caveats:

- there can be minor delays due to internal agent synchronization, but I've never seen this off by more than a few seconds
- if the first run at 2:00 takes *more* than 2 hours (but less than 4 hours), the next time the job runs will be at 6:00 (the 4:00 run is skipped, it doesn't run at 4:10 or 4:20 to "catch up")

There was another suggestion to add a WAITFOR to offset the start time (and we should discard random WAITFOR, because that is probably not what you want - random <> unique). If you want to hard-code a different delay on each instance (1 minute, 2 minutes, etc.) then it is much more straightforward to do that with a schedule than by adding steps to all of your jobs. IMHO.

Comment: That's why I put the URL to this page in my Tweet. The jobs generally finish in a few minutes (the databases are all under 10 GB). Variations of a few seconds don't worry me. I just don't want 50 log backups all trying to write to the same destination share at the same time. You seem to have provided that. Thanks!

I was looking for assurance that if I set those start time offsets now, I would get the expected results starting at 2:00 am tonight.

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I didn't click the link.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could setup a centralized DB that manages the "schedule" and have the jobs add/update a row when they run.  This way each subsequent server can start the job that "polls" when it can start.  This way any latency in the jobs will cause the others to wait so you don't have a disparity in your timings when one of the servers is thrown off.

Being a little paranoid I'd add a catchall scenario that says after "x" minutes of waiting proceed anyway so that a delay doesn't cascade far enough that the jobs don't run.

Comment: Very complicated. I don't want to have to set up linked servers on every instance so they could communicate with the central database and write a lot of code if just changing the start time on the job schedules will resolve the problem. It won't be a big deal if a few end up overlapping, but all of them hitting at one time is definitely a problem.